# How do you access the DisplayNameFor in a nested model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

How do you access the `DisplayNameFor` in a nested model - ie.:

```
public class Invoice
{
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    public string CustomerName { get; set; }
    public string Contact { get; set; }
    public IList<InvoiceItem> InvoiceItems { get; set; }
}

public class InvoiceItem
{
    public int InvoiceItemId { get; set; }
    public int InvoiceId { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Heading")]
    public string Item { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Item Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public virtual Invoice Invoice { get; set; }
}
```

I can loop through the nested items as follows:

```
     @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceItems)
     {
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
          <br />
          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
          <br />
     }
```

But I how do I get to: `[Display(Name = "Item Heading")]`

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.Item)
```

I get the error: `'inv5.Models.Invoice' does not contain a definition for 'Item' and no extension method 'Item' accepting a first argument of type 'inv5.Models.Invoice' could be found`

Thanks, Mark

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Here you're accessing the `item` in your loop:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
```

But here you're not:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.Item)
```

Change the latter to this and it should work:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => item.Item)
```

`modelItem` is of type `Invoice` (the model passed to the view), but in the loop you want to use `item` (from the loop iterator) which is of type `InvoiceItem`.

Side note: Debugging something like this might be a *lot* more straightforward if *everything* wasn't called "item."  Clear naming is important :)

**Edit:** If you're accessing it outside of the loop, then you need to drill down into the model manually.  Something like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.InvoiceItems.First().Item)
```

It *feels* like this would be dangerous, since `.First()` can throw an exception if there are no items.  However, as comments have indicated and some cursory Googling seems to confirm, `.First()` isn't *actually* executed at runtime in this case.  This is just a bit of trickery to allow `.DisplayNameFor()` to reflect down into the property.

Comment: Wow, I would've never noticed it, honestly was staring at it for couple of minutes :)))

Comment: Hi - point takere names - but I want to show the DisplayNameFor before entering the loop.  Currently if I change it as suggested, I get "The name 'item' does not exist in the current context" - thanks, Mark

Comment: @fixit: Outside the context of the loop is a different story entirely.  You can try something like `modelItem.InvoiceItems.First().Item`.  That _might_ throw an exception if the list is empty, depending on how `DisplayNameFor` actually works.  (I've never peeked at the internals of it.)

Comment: @David - That does not throw an exception, since `item.First()` will not be executed at runtime, just the `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>>` is passed to the method.

Comment: Hi @David - your suggestion worked - if you could amend your answer, I'll mark it as such - thank you, Mark

Answer (score 3):

You can create a DisplayTemplate for your `InvoiceItems`, say "InvoiceItemHeader":

```
@model IEnumerable<InvoiceItem>

@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Item)
<br />
@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Description)
```

The type of the model has to be `IEnumerable<T>`, as the [DisplayNameFor Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh833697%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) has an overload version for this type.

Then in your view you can display the template:

```
 @Html.DisplayFor(m => m.InvoiceItems, "InvoiceItemHeader")
 @foreach (var item in Model.InvoiceItems)
 {
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Item)
      <br />
      @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)
      <br />
 }
```

Comment: Great!  The simple realization that the IEnumerable<T> has the overload was critical.  I was using ICollection<T> and simply changing types made all the difference in my case.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried this, but it should work.

```
@Html.DisplayNameFor(modelItem => modelItem.First().InvoiceItems().First().Item)
```

DisplayNameFor extension method is nothing else than a method expecting a Memberexpression with this signature: `Expression<Func<TModel, TValue>> expression`

Comment: `.InvoiceItems().First()` what if no items in `invoiceItems`? Will give you error (likely crashing UI)

Comment: @FindOutIslamNow I don't think the expression will be evaluated at runtime, just like `@Html.DisplayNameFor(m => m.Description)` won't be evaluated. and also works if Model is null, too. Here are some basics about expression parsing. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/charlie/2008/01/31/expression-tree-basics/

Answer (score 0):

ASP.NET Core introduces the [`DisplayNameForInnerType()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.rendering.ihtmlhelper-1.displaynameforinnertype?view=aspnetcore-7.0) method which addresses this problem.
To get the display name for a nested model outside a loop when the current model is a collection, this method can be used like this:

```
@Html.DisplayNameForInnerType((InvoiceItem invoiceItem) => invoiceItem.Item)
```

Note that, here you specify the type of the lambda expression parameter (`InvoiceItem`, the inner type) explicitly.

This is because the method accepts an argument of type `Expression<Func<TModelItem,TResult>> expression`. The first generic parameter of `Func<>` does not use the generic parameter of the model `TModel`, but uses a new generic parameter `TModelItem` defined by the `DisplayNameForInnerType` method.